# Объединение двух LAN сетей

Tags: windows, сеть, lan

Необходимо объединить две LAN сети c видимостью в сетевом окружении, для роботы некоторых клиент-серверных программ.

Топология данной сети:

[image: топология данной сети]

Comment: Опишите подробнее конечную цель.  Что вы понимаете под " видимостью в сетевом окружении"? Добавить статические пути в оба маршрутизатора недостаточно?

Comment: Провайдер -> роутер (d-link dir320) -> свитч (если надо разделить сети, то управялемый свитч) -> компы.

Comment: Для обеспечения "видимости в сетевом окружении" придётся как минимум завести WINS-сервер, ибо бродкасты не маршрутизируются.

Answer (score 0):

В официальной документации [Manual_DIR-320_A1_rev_1_0_RUS.pdf](http://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/Router/DIR-320/Description/Manual_DIR-320_A1_rev_1_0_RUS.pdf) в разделе "Маршрутизация (Routing)" описано, как добавлять статические маршруты.

Для роутера 192.168.0.1 нужно добавить статический маршрут для WAN интерфейса в `Destination 192.168.5.0 Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0 Gateway 192.168.5.1` (надеюсь, что угадал, сверьтесь с настройками роутера 192.168.5.1).

Для роутера 192.168.5.1 нужно повторить, только `Destination 192.168.0.0` и `Gateway 192.168.0.1`

Comment: Этого хватит для маршрутизации трафика, но мало для "видимости в сетевом окружении".

Comment: "c видимостью в сетевом окружении, для роботы некоторых клиент-серверных программ" означает, что только для каких-то конкретных программ. Если вопрос про самбу, можно просто расширить маску сети до, например, 192.168.0.0/21, которая включит в себя обе существующих сети. И потребуется соединить линком LAN порты обоих роутеров.

Comment: *означает, что только для каких-то конкретных программ* Я сомневаюсь. Скорее автор хочет открыть "Сетевое окружение" и увидеть там иконки компьютеров, в т.ч. из другой подсети. При отсутствии WINS-сервера (и, возможно, DNS/WINS-шлюза) поиск (мастер-браузера или доступных узлов) выполняется только бродкастовыми запросами, которые не будут маршрутизироваться в другую подсеть - так что компьютеры из другой подсети не будут найдены и отображены. А доступность хостов из другой подсети по NetBIOS-именам элементарно решается правкой LMHOSTS.

Comment: мой предыдущий коммент решает все эти проблемы без необходимости править что-то на 500 компах

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что оба D-Link-a сконфигурированы как NAT-маршрутизаторы. В этом случае никакое расширение маски не поможет - бродкасты по-прежнему не будут маршрутизироваться. А если Вы на LAN-стороне попробуете указать подсеть 192.168.0.0/21, то не сможете прописАть маршрут за другой роутер.

Comment: Конечно же вы не правы, бродкасты будут ходить в рамках локальных линков, поэтому я и написал "потребуется соединить линком LAN порты обоих роутеров"

Comment: Пардон,этот момент я упустил. Хотя не знаю, насколько у автора такое возможно - объединение сетей в одну. DHCP опять же не обрадуется. Как не обрадуется и админ, что у клиентов появится теоретическая возможность пойти в мир через чужой шлюз.

Comment: Прописав маршуртизацию, я и пингуя ничего не добился, не то  что бы

Comment: @stajl в двух местах?